# How good is a DSLR video?

Tags: video, dslr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the minimum camera characteristics required to record a movie for cinema?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/3969/what-are-the-minimum-camera-characteristics-required-to-record-a-movie-for-cinem)

Can one send Nikon D 3200 or Canon 550 D video to any major film festival (after Reverse Telecine conversion)? Can this video be projected on a large screen...large enough to be displayed in front of 200-300 people? I am aware about the quality of canon 5d...please let me know about the video quality of cameras mentioned (canon 550d or Nikon D 3200).

Please also let me know if it's wiser to invest in a Nikon AF-S DX Nikkor 55-300 mm f/4.5-5.6G ED VR Lens; (considering i am concerned only about the video)? The 55-200 mm lens is much cheaper and i am not very sure (have not handled these lenses before) if 55-300 provides any considerable magnification over the 55-200 one. Please advise which one is significantly better considering the cost as well.

Comment: This question is not very well posed as it concerns some subjective questions. You could do a vimeo/youtube search with keywords like `Nikon d3200` and `Canon 550D`. If you choose the Canon 550D you could look into the custom firmware Magic Lantern to improve the video capabilities. Concerning the lenses: it is not clear either on what you exactly want to know. The 55-300 has around 50% more magnification, but I am not sure what you want with that data. Please split up your question and clarify.